# "Flutter" Fetch data from shared_preferences and provider before running the app

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider

I am creating a flutter app, I am using shared_preferences to store the themeMode and using provider to manage state. I am able to fetch the themeMode before my app starts but not able to run the provider function that sets the themeMode.

Following is my code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var isDarkTheme = prefs.getBool("isDarkTheme") ?? false;
    return runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => ThemeManager(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MyApp(isDarkActive: isDarkTheme),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

My Provider "State Management" code

```
class ThemeManager with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDark = false;

  void setThemeMode(bool themeMode) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("isDarkTheme", themeMode);
    _isDark = themeMode;
    debugPrint(_isDark.toString());
    notifyListeners();
    // return true;
  }

  void fetchTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var darkMode = prefs.getBool('isDarkTheme');
    if (darkMode != null) {
      _isDark = darkMode;
    } else {
      _isDark = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isDark => _isDark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise a single global shared preference variable which you can use everywhere in your app so that you don't have to initialise it every time you when you want to use it.

so create a signleton class like this,

```
class SharedPreferencesHelper {
  SharedPreferencesHelper._();

  late SharedPreferences prefs;

  Future<void> initialise() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static final SharedPreferencesHelper instance = SharedPreferencesHelper._();
}
```

now initialise this in `main()` like this,

```
void main()async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await SharedPreferencesHelper.instance.initialise();
}
```

now only use this variable where ever you want like this,

```
SharedPreferencesHelper.instance.prefs.getBool('key');
```

or create some functions inside your helper class,

```
Future<bool> getProperty(String key) async {
      return await prefs.getBool(key);
  }
```